# Visual Studio 17.6.6 (build 408) for Mac - Could not locate device support files for iOS17

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios17

I am able to run react-native app with Xcode 15 on iOS17 devices but not able to run Xamarin.Forms app through Visual Studio.

The application is getting built successfully but getting "Could not locate device support files" error while launching automatically. When I open the app manually, it crashes on launch.

Upon going through a couple of links I found that XCode does not have device support files for iOS17 as Xcode 15 and later uses a new device stack (CoreDevice) to communicate with devices.

Looking for a workaround to build and run Xamarin.Forms application on iOS 17 devices.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)